# Due to some reason Admin content database is corrupted

Tags: sharepoint-server, central-administration, content-database, sharepont

Due to some reason Admin content database is corrupted and therefore my central admin site showing message `500 INTERNAL SERVER ERROR` Is there any way to remove and add new Admin content database? What should I need to do?

Comment: Are you sure that the actual database is corrupted? That database holds all the configuration for central admin, even if you have a backup I'm unsure if everything would work after a restore.

Comment: Yes, its corrupted. Actually its mistakenly restored with some other Admin content db. So, What should i need to do, please give some suggestion?

Comment: Can I restore the entire farm?

Comment: If it was restored by mistake you might be able to restore a correct version if you have that as a backup? I think it might be easier to rebuild the farm completely.

Comment: Unfortunately I don't have backup.. What you suggest the best option in this case ? what should I need to do?

Comment: You might be able to create a new admin content database and then remove the sites: https://www.toddklindt.com/blog/Lists/Posts/Post.aspx?ID=233

Comment: Please check this article: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/attach-or-detach-content-databases